# batch file exit /B

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exit

I simply wish to leave a cmd.exe window open upon completion of a batch file like the following.  I am test launching it from Windows 7 Explorer, with cmd.exe version 6.1.7601.  Beeps and pause work fine, but I want to leave the cmd open to issue subsequent commands.

```
@echo off
:: wschloss Jul 2015
:: This batch runs if the laptop's Core Temp is close to critical
::   as determined by the "Core Temp" utility at
::   "C:\ORION\System Information\CoreTemp\64bit\Core Temp.exe"
:: http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/
:: 
   color 1F :: White on Blue
:: Beeps!
   echo .
   type c:\bill\beep.txt :: causes the Laptop to beep for attention
   cls
::
   echo .
   echo Laptop Critical Temperature Approaches!
   echo .
   echo Save Your Data and Cool me down NOW!
   echo .
   pause
   color
   exit /B
:: EOP
```

This seems trivial but I am obviously missing something.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Run from within a command prompt window `cmd /?` and read the output help explaining the difference on usage of parameter `/C` (close) which is by default used for batch files and usage of parameter `/K` (keep) which you should use on running this batch file. Then `exit /B` is not necessary at all in your batch file.

Comment: FYI the COLOR call won't work with ':: White on Blue' on the same line

Answer (score 2):

Add `cmd /k` to the end of your file to redirect the program to Command Prompt. (It will end your program, then, in the same window, open command prompt)

```
@echo off
:: wschloss Jul 2015
:: This batch runs if the laptop's Core Temp is close to critical
::   as determined by the "Core Temp" utility at
::   "C:\ORION\System Information\CoreTemp\64bit\Core Temp.exe"
:: http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/
:: 
color 1F :: White on Blue
:: Beeps!
echo .
type c:\bill\beep.txt :: causes the Laptop to beep for attention
cls
::
echo .
echo Laptop Critical Temperature Approaches!
echo .
echo Save Your Data and Cool me down NOW!
echo .
pause
color
cmd /k
:: EOP
```

That, and if you want the previous output cleared, you could of course add `cls` right before the `cmd /k`.

Comment: Thank you UnknownOctopus, that is now clear.  MOFI was also correct but I didn't understand till you clarified. BTW for those reading this; the solution preserves the environment setup in the batch, which is good, and what I was looking for, though I didn't explicitly state.  Thanks all!

Comment: This works, however, the batch script does not terminate until the child CMD process is closed, and your one window has two CMD processes running simultaneously. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31417114/1012053) for a simple method to let the script close and have only one CMD process running at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cmd /k yourbatchfile.bat` command line, then `exit /b` will work as you want it to.

Comment: Can you clarify?  I am using it for several different batches that I, depending on what I am doing, launch from Win Explorer, and sometimes I edit them on the fly in Notepad before launching, but I always want the resulting cmd window to "stick."  If I have to create shortcuts, that defeats the purpose.  I just used the batch above as an example, though it is called from an app, so your solution wouldn't work in that case.  See comments at beginning of batch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I open up a command window first, and then run my batch scripts from there, so my window does not close when the script ends.

If I want to be able to double click a script and have it run and the window remain open, then I create a shortcut that runs `cmd /k "myscript.bat"`.

But it sounds like you don't want to do either of the above. You could start a new CMD shell with the /K option within the same window using START /B. Your parent CMD shell will terminate when the script completes, but the child CMD shell will remain so the window will remain open.

```
@echo off
:: wschloss Jul 2015
:: This batch runs if the laptop's Core Temp is close to critical
::   as determined by the "Core Temp" utility at
::   "C:\ORION\System Information\CoreTemp\64bit\Core Temp.exe"
:: http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/
:: 
   color 1F :: White on Blue
:: Beeps!
   echo .
   type c:\bill\beep.txt :: causes the Laptop to beep for attention
   cls
::
   echo .
   echo Laptop Critical Temperature Approaches!
   echo .
   echo Save Your Data and Cool me down NOW!
   echo .
   pause
   color
   start /b cmd /k
   exit /B
:: EOP
```